# Paypal sandbox doesn't return to notify_url

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a paypal button like

```
<form action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="paypalPayment">
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
     <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="mybuttonid">
     <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="myipnlistener" />
     <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/es_ES/ES/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal, la forma rápida y segura de pagar en Internet.">
      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/es_ES/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></form>
```

where myipnlistener is a route to node controller that have ipn listener code offered by Paypal. The problem is that this controller is never been called. I setted ipn listener to on in account settings.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Flor26, have you tried validating that URL IPN endpoint? Could be a permission level with the file/s or root blocking the call. Try testing the endpoint here. https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/. What do you find, validated? Also, don't want to assume but you updated the IPN listner in the sandbox or production paypal account?